# Spring Batch dynamic scaling on q8s - is it working?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, parallel-processing, spring-batch, autoscaling

Does Anyone have the Spring Batch parallel / partitioned batch chunk-based processing working on Kubernetes using the DeployerPartitionHandler? That is: chunk-based partitioned processing with dynamic scaling in a q8s cluster. I find absolutely no concrete sample code on this exact approach. There are certainly info on all the other of the 4 different parallel Bach approaches within the Spring Batch framework, but I do not find detailed samples or even videos on this specific partitioning with dynamic scaling approach. Is it dead code within the framework? Would appreciate any pointers :)

Basically looking for a demo project on this, but at this point it does look like a dead end *crickets sound*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Spring Cloud Task offers remote partitioning using Spring Cloud Deployers.   A sample can be found here using the local deployer: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/partitioning/#building-the-application and here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/html/#batch-partitioning.     The docs need to be updated to discuss k8's and we have created a story for it here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues/895

Comment: Thanks. The samples does not address the k8 approach. I also noticed that the k8 story was not done, so yeah it is missing unfortunately